# Programa executa normalmente porem tem momentos que para no meio da execução e nao sai do lugar

Tags: python, python-3.x

Este programa é para sortear numeros para a mega sena. Consegui o resultado que queria, mas tem momentos que o programa para ou no meio ou no inicio da execução.
O usuario coloca a quantidade de palpites que ele quer. Mais o problema que estou tendo é que se o usuario pede 10 palpites, as vezes executa todos, mais tem vezes que nao, e ele nao apresenta erros.

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep
lista = [[]]
num = 0
cont = 0
print('=' * 30)
print('      JOGA NA MEGA SENA')
print('=' * 30)
quantos = int(input('Qual a quantidade de palpites: '))
print(f'===== Sorteando {quantos} Jogos =====')
while quantos != 0:
    quantos -= 1
    cont += 1
    for i in range(0, 6):
        num = randint(1, 60)
        if num not in lista[0]:
            lista[0].append(num)
        else:
            while num in lista[0]:
                num = randint(1, 60)
                lista[0].append(num)
        if i == 5:
            lista[0].sort()
            print(f'Jogo {cont}:{lista[0]}')
            sleep(1)
            for l in range(0, 6):
                lista[0].pop()
```

No caso  estou usando lista dentro de lista por conta de exercicios do curso. Se alguem puder me ajudar nisso fico grato.

Comment: Pode nos explicar as linhas 19~21? `while num in lista[0]`

Comment: é que os numeros nao podem se repetir, entao, esse while é para q se o numero que foi gerado aleatoriamente se repetir ele gerar outro e adicionar e so saira desse loop se for gerado um outro numero aleatorio

Comment: essa foi a forma que encontrei para gerar um outro valor diferente do que tem dentro da lista. e entao adicionar outro

Comment: Mas essa lista vai crescendo infinitamente e no final você faz `lista[0].pop()` apenas 6 vezes. O que significa que em algum momento todos os números vão estar na sua lista e não terá nenhum para sortear.

Comment: Aliás, isso é um loop infinito, pois a sua condição `while num in lista[0]`, mas você faz `lista[0].append(num)`, ou seja, você adiciona o número na lista e depois continua o loop se ele estiver na lista. A condição sempre será verdadeira.

Comment: Eu entendi oq voce quiz dizer. Mais ele so entra nessa condição se ja tiver aquele numero la dentro. 
entao no caso teria que por um .pop() no final desta condição em especifico né?

Comment: Não, pois não faria sentido você adicionar na lista e depois remover da lista. Faz um teste de mesa e reveja a condição que está usando.

Comment: ele nao gera uma lista infinita, pq quando tem 6 numeros dentro da lista eu do um print desses numeros e depois apago um por um com um for.

Comment: ta bom obg. Eu vou dar uma boa revisada nesse codigo. o problema que estou tendo msm é que acredito eu que ele esta se perdendo em algum momento nos loops

Comment: Na dúvida, teste. Adicione um `print` dentro desse laço e veja: https://ideone.com/K6E6uv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na sua lógica para não repetir os valores:

```
num = randint(1, 60)
if num not in lista[0]:
    lista[0].append(num)
else:
    while num in lista[0]:
        num = randint(1, 60)
        lista[0].append(num)
```

A ideia aqui é adicionar o `num` apenas se ele ainda não está em `lista[0]`, porém o seu `while` definirá um laço infinito, visto que a condição `while num in lista[0]` sempre será verdadeira já que você sempre adiciona `num` em `lista[0]`.

Você pode simplificar essa lógica fazendo:

```
num = randint(1, 60)
while num in lista[0]:
    num = randint(1, 60)
lista[0].append(0)
```

Ou seja, sorteia um valor, enquanto ele estiver em `lista[0]` sorteia um novo valor. Adiciona o valor em `lista[0]` apenas quando o laço finalizar.

Alterando isso seu código já funcionará.

## Alternativa

Você pode usar a função [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample) para simplificar o seu código. Ele já irá retornar um conjunto de valores únicos sorteados do seu conjunto.

```
from random import sample

quantos = int(input('Qual a quantidade de palpites: '))

for i in range(quantos):
    print( sorted(sample(range(1, 61), 6)) )
    #                    +----------+  |
    #                          |       |
    #             Conjunto de valores  |
    #                                  +-- Número de valores sorteados
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/8cajlF)</sup>

Comment: nossa, cara. vlw, tava a dias quebrando a cabeça com esse exercicio. 
Nao sabia da existencia dessa função em random. Vou fuçar essa função aqui.